# Digital Signage for Dynamic Web Pages

Tags: media, display, digital

Is there a **digital signage application** that can faithfully render a **dynamic web page** the way a browser does? I have tried a few vendors - NoviSign, Pickcel.com, etc. These are cloud-based solutions that offer access to an authoring tool (ran in a browser) that can upload your content to the vendor's servers. You then configure a **media player** which has the vendor's app installed (and connected to your digital TV display) to pull the content for display on the TV.

The issue I am running into is that when I tried a dynamic web page **content** on the media player application, the web page remains static on the TV screen (there are no problems with Powerpoint slideshows). It seems that the **JavaScript** behind the web page is not getting executed in the player. I tried looking hard for some configuration settings that's causing this but to no avail. The **ideal** media player application would be one that has an actual web browser built into it that can render any typical dynamic web page for display. Are you guys aware of any such offerings by any vendor in the market?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a signage product that addresses exactly the issues I posted here. If you have a need to display a dynamic web page faithfully (even one that requires a login) via a signage app, you can try https://screencloud.com/. They have a Dashboards widget that handles this requirement and is very easy to use. I'm not going to go into details here as you can easily google them. I looked long and hard to find this and hopefully somebody in the same situation will find this information useful.